# How to handle UTC difference while converting DateTime

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, dst

When I am trying to convert a date to AST and then convert it back to IST, why is there a difference of 1 hour?

```
var tesDate = DateTime.Parse("2015-09-01T03:30:00+05:30");
TimeZoneInfo tmz = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Atlantic Standard Time");

DateTime tesDate1 = DateTime.SpecifyKind(tesDate, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);
var earliestStartTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(tesDate1, tmz, TimeZoneInfo.Utc);

//Local Time is Now in IS 
var localEarliestStartTime = earliestStartTime.ToLocalTime();
```

> Actual OutPut {9/1/2015 12:00:00 PM}
>
> Expected Output {9/1/2015 01:00:00 PM}

Comment: Sorry, I can't see a question here.

Comment: Just don't use DateTime when offsets are involved, use DateTimeOffset.  DateTime doesn't have an offset. It's either UTC, unpsecified, or local (which is almost as ambiguous as unpsecified). The original 5:30 offset isn't used since you explitily treat the input as if it were UTC. And why are you using AST at all ???

Comment: @Richard, Why is there a difference of 1 hour between Actual Output and Expected while converting?

Comment: Verifiy if local timezone on your PC is UTC+5:30. It looks like it is UTC+5. You can use `TimeSpan offset = DateTimeOffset.Now.Offset;` to check it.

Answer (score 1):

> When I am trying to convert a date to AST and then convert it back to IST, why is there a difference of 1 hour?

Because you're not actually doing that conversion. You're doing something much more convoluted, and I'm not sure why.  I'll comment your code so you can see what you are doing:

```
// Parse a string with a fixed +05:30 Indian offset
// This is converting to the local time zone in the process (Kind == DateTimeKind.Local)
var tesDate = DateTime.Parse("2015-09-01T03:30:00+05:30");

// Get the Atlantic time zone
TimeZoneInfo tmz = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Atlantic Standard Time");

// Assign DateTimeKind.Unspecified, which removes the existing Local kind  (why?)
DateTime tesDate1 = DateTime.SpecifyKind(tesDate, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);

// Convert to UTC, pretending the time is in AST, when actually it's in the local zone
var earliestStartTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(tesDate1, tmz, TimeZoneInfo.Utc);

// Convert from UTC back to the local zone
var localEarliestStartTime = earliestStartTime.ToLocalTime();
```

This is a bit silly, and of course it will lead to the wrong values.  If your goal is to convert from IST to AST and back, then you should just do this:

```
TimeZoneInfo tzAtlantic = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Atlantic Standard Time");
TimeZoneInfo tzIndian = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("India Standard Time");

DateTimeOffset original = DateTimeOffset.Parse("2015-09-01T03:30:00+05:30");
DateTimeOffset atlantic = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(original, tzAtlantic);
DateTimeOffset indian = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(atlantic, tzIndian);
```

There's no need to involve either UTC or the local time zone, unless you have some other purpose that you didn't explain.